# printing during loop in Jupyter

Tags: python, printing, jupyter-notebook

I am running a loop over a list (a parameter grid) and trying to simply print the progress of the loop. I have found that it is an issue with my Jupyter notebook.

I have the following code to extract just the problem:

```
hiddens = [2, 3]
iters = [5, 10]

para_grid = [(hidden, it) 
             for hidden in hiddens
             for it in iters]

num_sets = len(para_grid)       # length = 4

curr_set = 1

for para_set in para_grid:

    print("Completed {: f}%".format(curr_set/num_sets * 100))
    curr_set += 1

    x = para_set

    print(x)
```

If I do this in a normal script and run it from a text editor or terminal, I am getting the expected output:

```
>>> Completed  25.000000%
(2, 5)
Completed  50.000000%
(2, 10)
Completed  75.000000%
(2, 5)
Completed  100.000000%
(2, 10)
```

When I do this in the Jupyter notebook, it is like the calculation of the progress above: `curr_set/num_sets * 100` just returns zero all the time. Here is the results printout:

```
Completed  0.000000%
(2, 5)
Completed  0.000000%
(2, 10)
Completed  0.000000%
(3, 5)
Completed  0.000000%
(3, 10)
```

Other ways I have tested have had some success, all of which leads me to think it is something to do with the `curr_set` value and then how it is updated. I can't fathom it though!

Other printing issues I have found when searching are to do with notebooks not printing during run-time, but rather dumping all output at the end (or in the Terminal that is running the notebook), but that isn't a problem I am having.

Comment: I got the right answer on Jupyter notebook using the same script that you gave (I use Python 3.6). Maybe you have to cast to float first: `float(curr_set)` before dividing number?

Comment: You are likely running Python 2 in your notebook.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I was indeed an idiot and oversaw this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your jupyter notebook is running python2.x.

By default, python 2 returns `0` if you divide two integers and the result is < 1.

A workaround is to add `from __future__ import division` to your code.

Another workaround, as titipat suggested in his comment, is to "force" one of your variable to behave like a float, e.g. by using `float(curr_set)` or by setting `curr_set` to `1.0`.